# Way to see how a question actually looks?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review-queue

In the review for suggested edits queue, there was this post:

https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/297636

[image]

Now the edit seems fine, but what are all the `&nbsp;`s doing there? I'm not that good (in my mind) of seeing how the mark-up will actually 'translate' into rendered html, especially when there are images in it. Is there a way to view the html of the answer, in the review queue?

Comment: I don't really like these edits. The editor should add their own answer, don't take someone else's junk and make it look nice. But it isn't a big deal.

Comment: I didn't check the link but it may have been the details from it? Was it just his own answer?

Comment: It was details from the link. But why give a lazy user who is too lazy to even write a good answer the credit of a great answer? That defeats the reputation system.

Comment: @Tim - I did check and it seems OK. Also, if unsure, you can check to see if it is just a user, or a experienced one :D... http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7453/slm . Also, a answer with information in it is much more useful than a link (which could be broken in future)

Comment: You don't mean HTML.

Comment: @Seth because the objective is to have good answers. The user in question is not very active on AU and does not care about rep here. He just took the time to make the existing answer actually useful. That seems like a great edit to me. The reputation system is supposed to give incentive, it is not an end in itself. Anyway, _anything_ that changes junk to not junk is a good thing. We shouldn't care who gets the credit if the user who deserves it doesn't.

Comment: @Terdon But it is better to answer it himself, and make it a good one than edit someone else's and they get the rep.

Comment: @Tim actually I strongly disagree. Any user who is selfless and generous enough to do something like this deserves praise. It is an example of someone doing something entirely for the site and for purely altruistic reasons. Are we really so rep-obsessed that we feel that's wrong? It would never have been a good answer anyway if it was just paraphrasing/copying the blog. All slm did was make it a useful answer and he did so only to help a site he does not frequent. We need more users like that not fewer.

Comment: But it makes no difference to the site whether it is his own answer, or someone elses, and it is better if it is his own answer because then someone who can't be bothered doesn't get rep. I'm not worried about him not getting, I'm worried about the OP getting more rep, and more privilegs.

Comment: @Seth - If I see a kernel of a sorta correct A I'm often inclined to make that one "THE" A rather than start another one. The use of `&nbsp;` is a fairly standard way to center images within posts on SE sites. There are a few other methods but that's the way I've done so on U&L and other sites when I write things up. At this point I'm not working here for rep 8-)

Comment: @Tim - see my comments to Seth (above), they pertain to you as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So to do this (I just found) is actually really easy, and I'm glad I didn't post the question :)

Up at the top is a button that says `rendered output`, click that and it automagically changes to the rendered html.

[image]

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: This is not HTML. HTML is markup. (And not Markdown, either!) This is the _rendered_ output.

Comment: It's the output rendered to HTML.